# Get values of a XML archive

Tags: xml, vb.net

I have a question. I'm trying to get some values of a XML archive. Right now I can list most of them but when it comes to the last 2 nodes I have a problem, I always get the firstchild of the first node. For example

```
<TipoSaldo CodTipoSaldo="1" Descripción="Principal">
      <Saldos>
        <Plazos>
          <Plazo Código="0" Descripción="Muy corto plazo">
            <Saldo CodEntidad="100" Instrumento="BEMSM" CodMoneda="30" Principal="100000" EjercicioAnterior="0.0000" EjercicioCorriente="0.0000" />
          </Plazo>
          <Plazo Código="2" Descripción="Mediano plazo">
            <Saldo CodEntidad="100" Instrumento="BEMV" CodMoneda="1" Principal="563870500000.0000" EjercicioAnterior="0.0000" EjercicioCorriente="0.0000" />
          </Plazo>
        </Plazos>
      </Saldos>
</TipoSaldo>
```

I can see the values of line *Saldo CodEntidad="100" Instrumento="BEMSM"* and thats ok but when I try to get the values with a for cicle for the same line on the other node *Saldo CodEntidad="100" Instrumento="BEMV"* I keep getting the same values of the FIRST node *Saldo CodEntidad="100" Instrumento="BEMSM" ...* and not *Saldo CodEntidad="100" Instrumento="BEMV"...* .

This is the section of the main code where I get the values

```vb
    'Iniciamos el ciclo de lectura
    For index = 0 To contador

        'Obtenemos el valor del codigo servicio
        Dim mServicio = elementos.FirstChild.ChildNodes.ItemOf(index).Attributes.GetNamedItem("CodServicio").Value
        list.Add(mServicio)

        'segundo contador para recorrer el nodo de tipo saldo
        Dim contador2 = elementos.FirstChild.FirstChild.FirstChild.ChildNodes.Count - 1

        For index2 = 0 To contador2

            'nodo Ej: <TipoSaldo CodTipoSaldo="" Descripción="">
            'obtenemos valores anteriores
            Dim mCodigoTipoSaldo = elementos.FirstChild.FirstChild.FirstChild.ChildNodes.ItemOf(index2).Attributes.GetNamedItem("CodTipoSaldo").Value
            Dim mDescTipoSaldo = elementos.FirstChild.FirstChild.FirstChild.ChildNodes.ItemOf(index2).Attributes.GetNamedItem("Descripción").Value
            list.Add(mCodigoTipoSaldo)
            list.Add(mDescTipoSaldo) 'agregamos datos a la lista

            'tercer contador para el nodo de plazos
            Dim contador3 = elementos.FirstChild.FirstChild.FirstChild.FirstChild.FirstChild.FirstChild.ChildNodes.Count - 1

            For index3 = 0 To contador3

                'nodo Ej: <Plazo Código="" Descripción="">
                Dim mCodigoTipoPlazo = elementos.FirstChild.FirstChild.FirstChild.FirstChild.FirstChild.FirstChild.ChildNodes.ItemOf(index3).Attributes.GetNamedItem("Código").Value
                Dim mDescTipoPlazo = elementos.FirstChild.FirstChild.FirstChild.FirstChild.FirstChild.FirstChild.ChildNodes.ItemOf(index3).Attributes.GetNamedItem("Descripción").Value
                list.Add(mCodigoTipoPlazo)
                list.Add(mDescTipoPlazo) 'agregamos datos a la lista

                'cuarto contador para nodo final de saldos
                Dim contador4 = elementos.FirstChild.FirstChild.FirstChild.FirstChild.FirstChild.FirstChild.FirstChild.ChildNodes.Count - 1

                Dim item As New Object 'creo un nuevo objeto para agregar a la lista y que no se repitan valores

                For index4 = 0 To contador4
                    'nodo Ej: <Saldo CodEntidad="100" Instrumento="BEMSM" ... EjercicioCorriente="0.0000" />
                    Dim mSaldoInstrumento = elementos.FirstChild.FirstChild.FirstChild.FirstChild.FirstChild.FirstChild.FirstChild.ChildNodes.ItemOf(index4).Attributes.GetNamedItem("Instrumento").Value
                    Dim mSaldoPrincipal = elementos.FirstChild.FirstChild.FirstChild.FirstChild.FirstChild.FirstChild.FirstChild.ChildNodes.ItemOf(index4).Attributes.GetNamedItem("Principal").Value
                    Dim mEjercicioCorriente = elementos.FirstChild.FirstChild.FirstChild.FirstChild.FirstChild.FirstChild.FirstChild.ChildNodes.ItemOf(index4).Attributes.GetNamedItem("EjercicioCorriente").Value

                    list.Add(mSaldoInstrumento)
                    list.Add(mSaldoPrincipal)
                    list.Add(mEjercicioCorriente) 'agregamos valores a la lista

                Next

                Console.Write(" Tipo Plazo: " & mCodigoTipoPlazo _
                & " Descripcion Tipo Plazo: " & mDescTipoPlazo _
                )

            Next
```

Any help or idea would be perfect !
Thanks a lot !

Comment: learn XPath, then you can do something like `elementos.SelectNodes("xpath expression here")` to get almost any part of the XML far easier

Comment: @har07 In fact I changed some lines and now I use xpath to obtain the specific nodes where I want to start looking for the attributes and it works ! thanks for the idea man !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your XML is wellformed then you can either use

- XPath: http://www.techrepublic.com/article/easily-navigate-xml-with-vbnet-and-xpath/
- Linq to XML: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx

That will at the least save you a lot of .FirstChild.FirstChild

Hope it helps!